# C# Linq query condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table

[image]

I want to grab only the customer where the status = 1 for all rows. so in this example it would only grab John since Bob has status=2 for one record.

I would like to do this in linq c#. Do I need to group it first for all customers? and then have another query to check if it doesn't contain <> 2 then print it?

what would be the right way?

Comment: post your code and we'll help you debug it

Comment: Sounds like you have a pretty good idea of where to start.  Make an attempt at implementing your ideas and see what problems you have with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were right on. Given:

```
class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

you'll want:

```
var names = customers.GroupBy(c => c.Name)
                     .Where(c => c.All(cc => cc.Status == 1))
                     .Select(c => c.Key)
                     .ToList();
```

1. Group By Name
2. Grab items where all `Status` = 1
3. Select the Names of the result

Answer (score 0):

var data=customers.where(c => c.status!=2).select(c=>c.Customer).Tolist().distnict();

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!